# Making one helper function for ByteBuffer allocation android OpenGL ES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, floatbuffer

For allocating `ByteBuffer` memory for vertices, colors, lighting, etc everytime I need to do the following.

```
      ByteBuffer bBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);    
      bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      vertBuff=bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      vertBuff.put(vertices);
      vertBuff.position(0);

      ByteBuffer bColorBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colorVals.length*4);
      bColorBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      colorBuff=bColorBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      colorBuff.put(colorVals);
      colorBuff.position(0);
        .......
```

So I tried making a helper function something like this.

```
   private void fBFromFA(float array[], int size, FloatBuffer theBuff){

      ByteBuffer bBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(array.length*size);    
      bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      theBuff=bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      theBuff.put(array);
      theBuff.position(0);

}
```

But it didnt work. it gave me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` pointing the source at 
`gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);` inside the void `draw(GL10 gl)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `theBuff` as an output parameter, but Java doesn't have these. Instead, return `bBuff`.

And there's no need to pass in `size`. Floats are always 4 bytes in Java. If you don't want the literal, use `Float.SIZE / 8` (because it's a count of bits).